# how can i destroy the empty or blank field in rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how can i use the 'reject_if' in rails . and destroy the empty or blank field

i am using this code of line

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_reals,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a.destroy if a[:twitter_url].blank? }#,reject_if:proc { |user_twitter_reals_attributes| attributes.all? { |key, value| key == '_destroy' || value.blank? } }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_chipcounts,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:twitter_url].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_twitter_fakes,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:twitter_url].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_cells,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:cell_number].blank? }
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_facebook_personals,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:facebook_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_facebook_fansites,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:facebook_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_facebook_fakes,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:facebook_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_social_account 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_websitess,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:site_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_wikipedias,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:wikipidea_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_imdbs,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:imdburl].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_googlepluss,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:gooplus_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_youtubes,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:youtube_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_myspaces,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:myspace_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_linkedins,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:linkedin_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_pinterests,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:pinterest_url].blank? } 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :usersetting,:allow_destroy => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_facebook_personals,:allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => proc { |a| a['facebook_url'].blank? }
```

Do same for rest

Comment: but how can i handle it on edit form where we make it blank .

Answer (score -1):

Like

`accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['password'].blank? }`

Please do the same for your nested attributes.

if there is all attributes blank, reject it like

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :location, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

Please refer [nested_attributs with proc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)